# Compare and Highlight the differences of two dataframes using spark and java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using **spark** and **java** to to try and compare two data frames.

Once I convert my csv files into data frames, I want to **highlight exactly what changed between two dataframes.**

They all have the same columns in common.

As you can see the only thing not correct with below data frames is **emp_id 4 in the second df2.**

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().csv("/Users/dataframeOne.csv");
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().csv("/Users/dataframeTwo.csv"); 
df1.unionAll(df2).except(df1.intersect(df2)).show(true);
```

Df1

```
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_name| emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|     3|  Chennai|  rahman|9848022330|  45000|SanRamon|
|     1|Hyderabad|     ram|9848022338|  50000|      SF|
|     2|Hyderabad|   robin|9848022339|  40000|      LA|
|     4|  sanjose|   romin|9848022331|  45123|SanRamon|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

Df2

```
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_name| emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|     3|  Chennai|  rahman|9848022330|  45000|SanRamon|
|     1|Hyderabad|     ram|9848022338|  50000|      SF|
|     2|Hyderabad|   robin|9848022339|  40000|      LA|
|     4|  sanjose|  romino|9848022331|  45123|SanRamon|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

Difference

```
+------+--------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|emp_id|emp_city|emp_name| emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|
+------+--------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|     4| sanjose|  romino|9848022331|  45123|SanRamon|
+------+--------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

How can I **highlight in yellow** 'Romino', the incorrect field using **JAVA** and **SPARK**?

Comment: Could you please add the example data as text (not as screenshot). This makes it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I think you're pretty close. `df1.except(df2)` gives you the rows in df1 but not in df2. So to know the difference between the two, run both `df1.except(df2)` and `df2.except(df1)`.

Comment: @m_vemuri It prints out the difference but is there a way to highlight the difference e.g. 'Romino' highlighted in yellow

Comment: @werner Hopefully its easier to read now?

Comment: @JoeyOC since this is all programmatic processing, highlighting cannot be done trivially. It will require a user-interface of some sort/possibly a BI tool.

Comment: @JoeyOC To do it programmatically, you will have to run comparisons against each row in one, against each row in the other. That will be expensive to do.

Comment: If the end goal is to fix the discrepancies, then I'd suggest using the `emp_id` and fixing the names that are different for the same `emp_id`. That will be done very quickly by Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting something in Spark depends on your GUI, so as first step I would suggest to detect the different values and add the information about the differences as additional column to the dataframe.

**Step 1:** Add a suffix to all columns of the two dataframes and join them over the primary key (`emp_id`):

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

private static Dataset<Row> prefix(Dataset<Row> df, String prefix) {
    for(String col: df.columns()) df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, col + prefix);
    return df;
}

[...]
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv(...);
Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv(...);

String[] columns = df1.columns();

Dataset<Row> joined = prefix(df1, "_1").join(prefix(df2, "_2"),
        col("emp_id_1").eqNullSafe(col("emp_id_2")), "full_outer");
```

**Step 2:** create a list of column objects that check if the value from one table is different from the other table. This list will later be used as input parameter for `map`.

```java
List<Column> diffs = new ArrayList<>();
for( String column: columns) {
    diffs.add(lit(column));
    diffs.add(when(col(column + "_1").eqNullSafe(col(column + "_2")), null)
            .otherwise(concat_ws("/", col(column + "_1"), col(column + "_2"))));
}
```

**Step 3:** create a new column containing a map with all differences:

```java
joined.withColumn("differences", map(diffs.toArray(new Column[]{})))
        .withColumn("differences", map_filter(col("differences"), (k, v) -> not(v.isNull())))
        .select("emp_id_1", "differences")
        .filter(size(col("differences")).gt(0))
        .show(false);
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------------------------+
|emp_id_1|differences               |
+--------+--------------------------+
|4       |{emp_name -> romin/romino}|
+--------+--------------------------+
```